# Function that copies elements of one array to another array using pointers

Tags: c++

I'm working my way through a textbook called *C++ Without
Fear* (I'm self-teaching & still in beginner phase). I'm totally
stumped on one of the exercises in the chapter on Pointers. This is
the exact wording of the exercise:

> "Write & test a `copy_array` function
>   that copies the contents of one `int` array to another array of the same
>   size. The function should take two pointer arguments. The operation
>   inside the loop should be as follows:
>
> ```
> *p1 = *p2;
> p1++;
> p2++;
> ```

I was able to build my program w/ out errors (whew) but my issue is
that when I go to print the second array to the screen after
calling the `copy_array` function, the result is the original elements
of that second array. I believe my issue is with my `copy_array`
function. I've spent the last 2 hours searching on the Internet for
similar exercises & their solutions but am still stumped. I did see
another Stack Overflow question that was similar to mine and it seemed
the solution had something to do w/ creating a copy of the pointers to
step through so the location of the 2 pointers isn't changing or
something like that...I tried my hardest to understand & visualize how
to do this but I'm still stumped. Ugh. Any help on this issue would be
very much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int arr2[10] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

void copy_array(int* p1, int* p2, int n)
{
    while (n-- > 0)
    {
        *p1 = *p2;
        p1++;
        p2++;       
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Contents of Array 1 before..." << endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr1[i] << " " << endl; 
    }

    cout << "Contents of Array 2 before..." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << " " << endl; 
    }

    copy_array(arr1, arr2, 10);

    cout << "Contents of Array 2 after..." << endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << " " << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also print `arr1` after you call your function and you'll see the problem. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging stuff like this yourself. Staring at your code for more than a few minutes or searching the internet when debugging usually doesn't help much.

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error on the `copy_array(arr1, arr2, 10);` line. Alexander Zhang gave good debugging advice for those who should learn to debug this on their own (e.g. anyone self-teaching & still in beginner phase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
*p1 = *p2;
```

*p1 
"dereferences" the p1 pointer, this means that anything assigned to this will be assigned to the address indicated by p1.

*p2 "dereferences" the p2 pointer, any read of this location will be a read of the value stored at the address indicated by p2.

```
p1++;
```

This increments the address pointer by 1, this does not mean 1 byte, this means 1 increment of the size stored in p1, in this case its an int, so it increments the address by sizeof(int).

```
p2++; // Does the same as p1++.
```

So in this case your assigning to the p1 array, not assigning to the p2 array.

```
*p1 = *p2;
```

Means:
Copy the value stored at address p2 into address p1. p1 is the memory that changes.

Although not completely type safe memcpy has some advantages that a hand rolled function may not. memcpy will end up with nearly optimial code generation with is really nice. I hope that I have interpretted your question correctly, memcpy takes pointers.

```
template <typename T>
bool safe_copy(T * dest, size_t dest_count, const T * source, size_t source_count)
{
    auto const dest_bytes = sizeof(dest[0]) * dest_count;
    auto const source_bytes = sizeof(source[0]) * source_count;
    //
    //
    if (dest_bytes < source_bytes) return false;
    //
    //
    return memcpy( (void*)dest, (const void *)source, sizeof(source[0]) * source_count ) == dest;
}
```

Please not many vendors banned the use of memcpy for the reasons listed in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb288454(v=msdn.10)

It is often recommended to use memcpy_s instead, but this isn't always avaliable.

You can see my proposed solution here:
https://onlinegdb.com/HJlybSLVH

EDIT:
As discussed in the comments below, the standard C++ approach is using

```
std::copy
std::copy_n
std::copy_if
std::copy_backward
std::reverse_copy
std::replace_copy
std::replace_copy_if
std::unique_copy
```

A great resource for these is here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm

These achieve the same thing but are generalised to the concept of iterators. Because you asked about pointers, I posted about memcpy, which deals with pointers only.

Comment: The whole point is that OP is practicing with pointers. Even if that's not the case you should be using [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n), which as far as I know can easily be optimized into `memcpy` here.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Yeah, for trivially copyable types `std::copy` or `std::copy_n` are likely to use `memcpy` or `memmove` to do bulk copying.

Comment: Good point, I was trying to keep the answer to pointers and not generalised to iterators.
I'll add a section for copy_n.

Comment: Pointers are iterators.

Comment: Yes, but its a more general concept. I didn't want to complicate the answer. copy could take, begin and end of a list. These iterators are not just pointers. It could also hook into IO or other peripherals that don't have addressable memory at all. 
It wasn't within the scope of the question to explain why the parameters of std::copy don't have a pointer type (they obviously do once type deduction takes place).

He was asking about pointers, but your right about <algorithm> functions being safer and recommended for use.

Comment: Pointers are iterators in some situations. But the statement isn't reversable. Iterators are not pointers.

Comment: Thank you both so much for the help! I'm super grateful as well for that link on how to debug as I've been looking for resources on how to actually learn debugging since this subject is skimmed over in so many videos I watch & in the textbook I'm working my way through. Thank you thank you!